# Why do I need to make deploy of restful web service to get the latest updates from the database

Tags: database, rest, netbeans, jersey

I am developing a java restful webservice using netbeans and jersey api. when I update data in database the findall method didn't get the latest changes from the database unless I deploy the webservice again. how can I solve this without deploying the webservice again.

Note : `insert` and `delete` works good

Comment: Are you using a persistence framework? Are you using a cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this

```
em.refresh(object o)
```

and it solved my problem